# reject all subdomains with nginx and ssl.

Tags: ssl, nginx, configuration

Since I only have a single domain cert I would like to reject all subdomains (*.domain.com) with a nginx return code 444 and allow just the base domain (domain.com).  This config below seems like it match all the subdomains of domain.com.

```
server {
    listen 443;

    /* ssl cert stuff */

    server_name domain.com

}
```

I tried to add the snippet below after the snippet above as a catch all but that didn't seem to work either.

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name .domain.com
    reject 444
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27019854/372643).

Comment: I don't want to redirect because I know the certs aren't valid, I just want to terminate the connection.

Comment: That's point number 2 in that question. Essentially, that's not going to happen unless you get a cert for `*.domain.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your config for SSL reject to:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name *.domain.com;
  return 444;
}
```